# Attribute of an object is not updated when changing the state with StateFlow in Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

I followed the last Google tutorials to introduce Compose/ViewModel/State in a new project, but I encounter a problem that I don't understand. When I use a method in Viewmodel to update an object from null to new instance, UI is updated, but when I use the same method to update just a parameter of this object, the modification is not visible.

Here the code
ViewModel

```
data class AppOscarUiState(
val selectedStep: Step? = null
)

class AppViewModel() : ViewModel(){
  private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(AppUiState())
  val uiState: StateFlow<AppUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

  fun updateSelectedStep(newStep: step){
    _uiState.update { currentState ->
        currentState.copy(selectedStep = newStep)
    }
  // also tried _uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy(selectedStep = newStep)

  }
}
```

And in the Composable

````
fun CardDetail(
    appViewModel: AppViewModel
) {
    val appUiState by appViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

   Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
    ) {
    Text(
                    text = appUiState.selectedStep!!.status,
                )
    OutlinedButton(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedStep!!.status = 16
                        appViewModel.updateSelectedStep(selectedStep)
                    },
                ) {
                    Text(
                        stringResource(R.string.it_starts),
                    )
                }
    }

When the step is selected from a list, ```updateSelectedStep(newStep)``` from the viewmodel is called and a detail container is filled. And when I want to change a parameter, the same is done. A log in ```updateSelectedStep(newStep)``` indicates that the new value is well transmetted, and when the step is deselected and selected again, the new data is visible.
Step is a data class.

So why the modification is not instantaneous ? I have a similar method to update a boolean (not an object) which works fine.

Thanks for your help
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the same object to `currentState.copy(selectedStep = newStep)` - you can log object address to see it - from Compose perspective it means that object hasn't changed, so no recomposition is needed.

One option is to define `status` as `mutableStateOf`, in this case you won't need too update state with `copy`:

```
var status by mutableStateOf(0)
```

But if you wanna split your code into view/data layers for better testability/to make it cleaner, you shouldn't use `var` for properties you wanna update, and use `copy` on all levels:

```
appViewModel.updateSelectedStep(selectedStep!!.copy(status = 16))
```